# Compiling with Xelatex on one PC works, the other doesn't despite same setup

Tags: xetex

I have this document:

```
\documentclass
  [
    captions=topbeside,
    oneside, DIV=12, 12pt, ngerman
  ]
  {scrreprt}


\marginparwidth=2.5cm
\textwidth=12.5cm
\hoffset = 0cm
\voffset = 2cm
\textheight = 20.5cm
\headsep = 1cm
\footskip = 2cm
\marginparsep = -15.2cm
\oddsidemargin = 3.36cm
\evensidemargin = 3.36cm

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}


\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Frutiger LT 45 Light}


\usepackage{mcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{ragged2e}


\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\cftdot}{}


\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
\clearscrheadfoot
\rofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\cfoot[\small Platzhalter]{\small Platzhalter}
\lehead{\leftmark}
\rohead{\leftmark}


\usepackage{romanbarpagenumber}



\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{caption}
\captionsetup{format=plain}
\captionsetup[margincap]{indention=0pt,justification=RaggedLeft}

\captionsetup[figure]{name={Bild}}

%\usepackage{showframe}% shows the page layout


\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Quellenverzeichnis/Quellen-MA.bib}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{}
%\usepackage{cite}


\usepackage{header}

\def\table{\def\figurename{Tabelle}\figure}
\let\endtable\endfigure 

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{placeins}

\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{diagbox}

\usepackage{pdfpages}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{units}



\newcommand\bootstrapsamples{N_\text P}
\newcommand\gausswidth{\sigma}
\newcommand\initialrandomwidth{\tilde \Delta}
\newcommand\iterations{M}
\newcommand\iterationsbetween{M_\text{Zw}}
\newcommand\margin{\Delta}
\newcommand\mass{\mu}
\newcommand\preiterations{M'}
\newcommand\rounds{\bar n}
\newcommand\timesites{N}
\newcommand\timestep{a}





\begin{document}

\includepdf[pages={1-2}, fitpaper=true]{Deckblatt.pdf}



\begin{adjustwidth}{-2.7cm}{0pt}
    \tableofcontents
\end{adjustwidth}

\pagenumbering{Roman}

\begin{adjustwidth}{-2.7cm}{0pt}
    \cleardoublepage
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
    \listoffigures
\end{adjustwidth}



\begin{adjustwidth}{-2.7cm}{0pt}
    \cleardoublepage
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}
    \listoftables
\end{adjustwidth}






\newpage

\input{thesis_text.tex}





\end{document}
```

The compiling on my main machine works flawlessly but it doesn't compile on my laptop which has the same packages installed and also the same font. Therefor i am not able to interpret the Error:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (MiKTeX 2.9.7050 64-bit) (preloaded format=xelatex 2019.7.3)  17 JUL 2019 19:23
entering extended mode
**./Masterarbeit.tex
(Masterarbeit.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>

(C:\Users\Christoph\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\scrreprt.c
ls
Document Class: scrreprt 2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script document class (report)

(C:\Users\Christoph\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\scrkbase.s
ty
Package: scrkbase 2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent b
asics and keyval usage)

(C:\Users\Christoph\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\scrbase.st
y
Package: scrbase 2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent 
basics and keyval usage)
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty"
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
(C:\Users\Christoph\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\scrlfile.s
ty
Package: scrlfile 2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (loading files)

Package scrlfile, 2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
                  Copyright (C) Markus Kohm

)))
(C:\Users\Christoph\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\tocbasic.s
ty
Package: tocbasic 2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
)
Package tocbasic Info: omitting babel extension for `toc'
(tocbasic)             because of feature `nobabel' available
(tocbasic)             for `toc' on input line 117.
Package tocbasic Info: omitting babel extension for `lof'
(tocbasic)             because of feature `nobabel' available
(tocbasic)             for `lof' on input line 118.
Package tocbasic Info: omitting babel extension for `lot'
(tocbasic)             because of feature `nobabel' available
(tocbasic)             for `lot' on input line 119.
Package tocbasic Info: defining new hook before heading of `' on input line 112
3.
Class scrreprt Info: You've used standard option `oneside'.
(scrreprt)           This is correct!
(scrreprt)           Internally I'm using `twoside=false'.
(scrreprt)           If you'd like to set the option with \KOMAoptions,
(scrreprt)           you'd have to use `twoside=false' there
(scrreprt)           instead of `oneside', too.
Package scrbase Info: Unknown processing state.
(scrbase)             Processing option `twoside=false'
(scrbase)             of member `.scrreprt.cls'
(scrbase)             of family `KOMA'
(scrbase)             doesn't set a valid state.
(scrbase)             This will be interpreted
(scrbase)             as \FamilyKeyStateProcessed on input line 1274.
Package scrreprt Info: You've used standard option `12pt'.
(scrreprt)             This is correct!
(scrreprt)             Internally I'm using `fontsize=12pt'.
(scrreprt)             If you'd like to set the option with \KOMAoptions,
(scrreprt)             you'd have to use `fontsize=12pt' there
(scrreprt)             instead of `12pt', too.
Class scrreprt Info: File `scrsize12pt.clo' used to setup font sizes on input l
ine 1655.

(C:\Users\Christoph\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\scrsize12p
t.clo
File: scrsize12pt.clo 2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script font size class option (12pt
)
)
(C:\Users\Christoph\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\typearea.s
ty
Package: typearea 2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (type area)

Package typearea, 2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (type area)
                  Copyright (C) Frank Neukam, 1992-1994
                  Copyright (C) Markus Kohm, 1994-

\ta@bcor=\skip41
\ta@div=\count80
Package typearea Info: You've used standard option `oneside'.
(typearea)             This is correct!
(typearea)             Internally I'm using `twoside=false'.
(typearea)             If you'd like to set the option with \KOMAoptions,
(typearea)             you'd have to use `twoside=false' there
(typearea)             instead of `oneside', too.
\ta@hblk=\skip42
\ta@vblk=\skip43
\ta@temp=\skip44
\footheight=\skip45
Package typearea Info: These are the values describing the layout:
(typearea)             DIV  = 12
(typearea)             BCOR = 0.0pt
(typearea)             \paperwidth      = 597.50793pt
(typearea)              \textwidth      = 448.13095pt
(typearea)              DIV departure   = -6%
(typearea)              \evensidemargin = 2.4185pt
(typearea)              \oddsidemargin  = 2.4185pt
(typearea)             \paperheight     = 845.04694pt
(typearea)              \textheight     = 635.5pt
(typearea)              \topmargin      = -41.72441pt
(typearea)              \headheight     = 18.125pt
(typearea)              \headsep        = 21.75pt
(typearea)              \topskip        = 12.0pt
(typearea)              \footskip       = 50.75pt
(typearea)              \baselineskip   = 14.5pt
(typearea)              on input line 1330.
)
\c@part=\count81
\c@chapter=\count82
\c@section=\count83
\c@subsection=\count84
\c@subsubsection=\count85
\c@paragraph=\count86
\c@subparagraph=\count87
LaTeX Info: Redefining \textsubscript on input line 3213.
\abovecaptionskip=\skip46
\belowcaptionskip=\skip47
\c@pti@nb@sid@b@x=\box27
\c@figure=\count88
\c@table=\count89
\bibindent=\dimen102
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/fontspec\fontspec.sty"
(C:\Users\Christoph\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/l3packages/xparse\xpar
se.sty
(C:\Users\Christoph\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2014/09/15 v5423 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(C:\Users\Christoph\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3-code.te
x
Package: expl3 2014/09/15 v5423 L3 programming layer (code) 
L3 Module: l3bootstrap 2014/08/23 v5354 L3 Bootstrap code
 (C:\Users\Christoph\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/etex-pkg\etex.sty
Package: etex 2016/08/01 v2.7 eTeX basic definition package (PEB,DPC)
\et@xins=\count90
)
L3 Module: l3names 2014/08/22 v5343 L3 Namespace for primitives
L3 Module: l3basics 2014/08/24 v5364 L3 Basic definitions
L3 Module: l3expan 2014/08/22 v5349 L3 Argument expansion
L3 Module: l3tl 2014/08/24 v5359 L3 Token lists
L3 Module: l3str 2014/08/24 v5368 L3 Strings
L3 Module: l3seq 2014/08/23 v5354 L3 Sequences and stacks
L3 Module: l3int 2014/09/14 v5421 L3 Integers
\c_max_int=\count91
\l_tmpa_int=\count92
\l_tmpb_int=\count93
\g_tmpa_int=\count94
\g_tmpb_int=\count95
L3 Module: l3quark 2014/08/23 v5354 L3 Quarks
L3 Module: l3prg 2014/08/23 v5354 L3 Control structures
\g__prg_map_int=\count96
L3 Module: l3clist 2014/08/23 v5354 L3 Comma separated lists
L3 Module: l3token 2014/09/15 v5422 L3 Experimental token manipulation
L3 Module: l3prop 2014/08/23 v5354 L3 Property lists
L3 Module: l3msg 2014/08/24 v5358 L3 Messages
L3 Module: l3file 2014/08/24 v5369 L3 File and I/O operations
\l_iow_line_count_int=\count97
\l__iow_target_count_int=\count98
\l__iow_current_line_int=\count99
\l__iow_current_word_int=\count100
\l__iow_current_indentation_int=\count101
L3 Module: l3skip 2014/08/23 v5354 L3 Dimensions and skips
\c_zero_dim=\dimen103
\c_max_dim=\dimen104
\l_tmpa_dim=\dimen105
\l_tmpb_dim=\dimen106
\g_tmpa_dim=\dimen107
\g_tmpb_dim=\dimen108
\c_zero_skip=\skip48
\c_max_skip=\skip49
\l_tmpa_skip=\skip50
\l_tmpb_skip=\skip51
\g_tmpa_skip=\skip52
\g_tmpb_skip=\skip53
\c_zero_muskip=\muskip10
\c_max_muskip=\muskip11
\l_tmpa_muskip=\muskip12
\l_tmpb_muskip=\muskip13
\g_tmpa_muskip=\muskip14
\g_tmpb_muskip=\muskip15
L3 Module: l3keys 2014/08/23 v5354 L3 Key-value interfaces
\g__keyval_level_int=\count102
\l_keys_choice_int=\count103
L3 Module: l3fp 2014/08/22 v5336 L3 Floating points
\c__fp_leading_shift_int=\count104
\c__fp_middle_shift_int=\count105
\c__fp_trailing_shift_int=\count106
\c__fp_big_leading_shift_int=\count107
\c__fp_big_middle_shift_int=\count108
\c__fp_big_trailing_shift_int=\count109
\c__fp_Bigg_leading_shift_int=\count110
\c__fp_Bigg_middle_shift_int=\count111
\c__fp_Bigg_trailing_shift_int=\count112
L3 Module: l3box 2014/08/23 v5354 L3 Experimental boxes
\c_empty_box=\box28
\l_tmpa_box=\box29
\l_tmpb_box=\box30
\g_tmpa_box=\box31
\g_tmpb_box=\box32
L3 Module: l3coffins 2014/08/23 v5354 L3 Coffin code layer
\l__coffin_internal_box=\box33
\l__coffin_internal_dim=\dimen109
\l__coffin_offset_x_dim=\dimen110
\l__coffin_offset_y_dim=\dimen111
\l__coffin_x_dim=\dimen112
\l__coffin_y_dim=\dimen113
\l__coffin_x_prime_dim=\dimen114
\l__coffin_y_prime_dim=\dimen115
\c_empty_coffin=\box34
\l__coffin_aligned_coffin=\box35
\l__coffin_aligned_internal_coffin=\box36
\l_tmpa_coffin=\box37
\l_tmpb_coffin=\box38
\l__coffin_display_coffin=\box39
\l__coffin_display_coord_coffin=\box40
\l__coffin_display_pole_coffin=\box41
\l__coffin_display_offset_dim=\dimen116
\l__coffin_display_x_dim=\dimen117
\l__coffin_display_y_dim=\dimen118
L3 Module: l3color 2014/08/23 v5354 L3 Experimental color support
L3 Module: l3candidates 2014/08/24 v5366 L3 Experimental additions to l3kernel
\l__box_top_dim=\dimen119
\l__box_bottom_dim=\dimen120
\l__box_left_dim=\dimen121
\l__box_right_dim=\dimen122
\l__box_top_new_dim=\dimen123
\l__box_bottom_new_dim=\dimen124
\l__box_left_new_dim=\dimen125
\l__box_right_new_dim=\dimen126
\l__box_internal_box=\box42
\l__coffin_bounding_shift_dim=\dimen127
\l__coffin_left_corner_dim=\dimen128
\l__coffin_right_corner_dim=\dimen129
\l__coffin_bottom_corner_dim=\dimen130
\l__coffin_top_corner_dim=\dimen131
\l__coffin_scaled_total_height_dim=\dimen132
\l__coffin_scaled_width_dim=\dimen133
)
(C:\Users\Christoph\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/l3kernel\l3unicode-dat
a.def
File: l3unicode-data.def 2014/08/12 v5276 L3 Unicode data
)
(C:\Users\Christoph\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/l3kernel\l3xdvipdfmx.d
ef
File: l3xdvidpfmx.def 2014/08/24 v5366 L3 Experimental driver: xdvipdfmx
))
Package: xparse 2014/09/15 v5423 L3 Experimental document command parser
\l__xparse_current_arg_int=\count113
\l__xparse_m_args_int=\count114
\l__xparse_mandatory_args_int=\count115
\l__xparse_processor_int=\count116
\l__xparse_v_nesting_int=\count117
)
Package: fontspec 2019/03/15 v2.7c Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX

! Undefined control sequence.
l.27 \sys_if_engine_luatex:T

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/luatex/luaotfload\luaotfload.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\ltluatex.tex"
File: ltluatex.tex 2018/10/21 v1.1i LuaTeX support for plain TeX (core) 

! Undefined control sequence.
l.55 \ifnum\luatexversion
                         <60 %
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   <
l.55 \ifnum\luatexversion<
                          60 %
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

***************************************************
* LuaTeX version too old for ltluatex support *
***************************************************
)
Package: luaotfload 2018/10/28 v.2.93 OpenType layout system

! Undefined control sequence.
l.47 \directlua
               {
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.


! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.48   i
        f xpcall(function ()%
You're in trouble here.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.50             end,texio.write_
                                 nl) then %
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.

LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <12> on input line 50.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <8> on input line 50.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <6> on input line 50.
! Extra }, or forgotten $.
l.55 }

I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.

)
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \lua_now:e 

l.30     \lua_now:e
                   {require("fontspec")}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/fontspec\fontspec-luatex.sty"
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.41 

I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.


Overfull \hbox (253.15054pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 48--41
[]\TU/lmr/m/n/12 if xpcall(function ()require(’luaotfload-main’)end,texio.write
$[]\OML/cmm/m/it/12 l\OT1/cmr/m/n/12 )\OML/cmm/m/it/12 thenlocal[]oid \OT1/cmr/
m/n/12 = \OML/cmm/m/it/12 luaotfload:main\OT1/cmr/m/n/12 ()\OML/cmm/m/it/12 els
etexio:write[]l\OT1/cmr/m/n/12 ([]\OML/cmm/m/it/12 Errorinluaotfload \OMS/cmsy/
m/n/12 ^^@
 []

Package: fontspec-luatex 2019/03/15 v2.7c Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaT
eX
\l__fontspec_script_int=\count118
\l__fontspec_language_int=\count119
\l__fontspec_strnum_int=\count120
\l__fontspec_tmp_int=\count121
\l__fontspec_tmpa_int=\count122
\l__fontspec_tmpb_int=\count123
\l__fontspec_tmpc_int=\count124
\l__fontspec_em_int=\count125
\l__fontspec_emdef_int=\count126
\l__fontspec_strong_int=\count127
\l__fontspec_strongdef_int=\count128
\l__fontspec_tmpa_dim=\dimen134
\l__fontspec_tmpb_dim=\dimen135
\l__fontspec_tmpc_dim=\dimen136
\g__file_internal_ior=\read1
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\fontenc.sty"
Package: fontenc 2018/08/11 v2.0j Standard LaTeX package

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\tuenc.def"
File: tuenc.def 2018/08/11 v2.0j Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding TU on input line 82.
))
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \fontspec with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 597.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmainfont with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 602.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setsansfont with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 607.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmonofont with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 612.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmathrm with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 616.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setboldmathrm with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 620.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmathsf with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 624.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmathtt with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 628.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setromanfont with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 632.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontfamily with sig. 'mO{}mO{}' on line 636.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \renewfontfamily with sig. 'mO{}mO{}' on line 640.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setfontfamily with sig. 'mO{}mO{}' on line 644.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \providefontfamily with sig. 'mO{}mO{}' on line 648.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontface with sig. 'mO{}mO{}' on line 652.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \renewfontface with sig. 'mO{}mO{}' on line 656.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setfontface with sig. 'mO{}mO{}' on line 660.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \providefontface with sig. 'mO{}mO{}' on line 664.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \defaultfontfeatures with sig. 't+om' on line 671.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \addfontfeatures with sig. 'm' on line 675.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \addfontfeature with sig. 'm' on line 679.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontfeature with sig. 'mm' on line 683.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newAATfeature with sig. 'mmmm' on line 687.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newopentypefeature with sig. 'mmm' on line 691.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newICUfeature with sig. 'mmm' on line 695.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \aliasfontfeature with sig. 'mm' on line 699.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \aliasfontfeatureoption with sig. 'mmm' on line 703.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontscript with sig. 'mm' on line 707.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontlanguage with sig. 'mm' on line 711.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \DeclareFontExtensions with sig. 'm' on line 715.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \IfFontFeatureActiveTF with sig. 'mmm' on line 719.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \liningnums with sig. 'm' on line 730.
.................................................

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...ntspec_parse_cv:w ####1\c_colon_str 
                                                  ####2\c_colon_str ####3\ex...
l.2845   }

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...####1\c_colon_str ####2\c_colon_str 
                                                  ####3\exp_not:N \q_nil {\_...
l.2845   }

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...ec_parse_cv:w ########1\c_colon_str 
                                                  0\c_colon_str \exp_not:N \...
l.2845   }

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...########1\c_colon_str 0\c_colon_str 
                                                  \exp_not:N \q_nil }}}
l.2845   }

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \EncodingCommand with sig. 'mO{}m' on line 3518.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \EncodingAccent with sig. 'mm' on line 3524.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \EncodingSymbol with sig. 'mm' on line 3530.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \EncodingComposite with sig. 'mmm' on line 3536.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \EncodingCompositeCommand with sig. 'mmm' on line 3542.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \DeclareUnicodeEncoding with sig. 'mm' on line 3567.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \UndeclareSymbol with sig. 'm' on line 3573.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \UndeclareAccent with sig. 'm' on line 3579.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \UndeclareCommand with sig. 'm' on line 3585.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \UndeclareComposite with sig. 'mm' on line 3592.
.................................................
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/fontspec\fontspec.cfg")
LaTeX Info: Redefining \itshape on input line 3783.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \slshape on input line 3788.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \scshape on input line 3793.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \upshape on input line 3798.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \em on input line 3828.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \emph on input line 3853.



)
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\fontspec-luatex.sty-h@@k ...spec-luatex.sty-h@@k 
                                                  \let \@unprocessedoptions ...
l.32     \endinput

If you really absolutely need more capacity,
you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.


Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 9849 strings out of 427702
 243402 string characters out of 3149662
 368052 words of memory out of 3000000
 13913 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 6392 words of font info for 25 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1334 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 5000i,2n,51p,10431b,4076s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
No pages of output.
```

Comment: Your expl3-packages are quite old.  But your format and fontspec is new, so you probably updated miktex only in admin mode and not also in user mode.

Comment: Dang i didn't know that there is a difference. You fixed my problem, thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An answer was provided by [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer) in a comment:

> Your expl3-packages are quite old. But your format and fontspec is new, so you probably updated miktex only in admin mode and not also in user mode.